# Account base: options.password must be a string

Tags: reactjs

I looked into some similar problems and added `.value`. But always get error:  `options.password must be a string`, even I cast the password.value.toString().

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

class Register extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

  handleSubmit (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.email.value);
    console.log(this.password.value);
    const res = Accounts.createUser(this.email.value, this.password.value.toString());
    console.log(res);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input className="form-control" type="email" ref={(email) => this.email = email}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input className="form-control" type="password" ref={(password) => this.password = password}/>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Comment: This looks like an error related to your logic on server. What do you get for ` console.log(this.password.value);` ??

Comment: I can get the correct password value and if I use typeof, it is also string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object, not 2 string arguments:

```
const res = Accounts.createUser({
  email: this.email.value,
  password: this.password.value,
});
```

**EDIT:**
About your React component, using states and [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) is a better practice than refs:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

class Register extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       email: '',
       password: '',
     }

     this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   }

   handleInputChange(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const name = target.name;

      this.setState({
        [name]: value,
      });
    }

  handleSubmit (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = Accounts.createUser({
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input className="form-control" type="email" name="email" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="password">Password:</label>
          <input className="form-control" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW, you forgot to bind the handleInputChange function and this.setState should be `[name]: target.value,`

Comment: Yes, I wrote it quickly and didn't test it. Glad you solved your problem. :)